# Trying to filter a dictionary for an AI

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Hi so I'm currently taking a class and one of our assignments is to create a Hangman AI. There are two parts to this assignment and currently I am stuck on the first task, which is, given the state of the hangman puzzle, and a list of words as a dictionary, filter out non-possible answers to the puzzle from the dictionary. As an example, if the puzzle given is t--t, then we should filter out all words that are not 4 letters long. Following that, we should filter out words which do not have t as their first and last letter (ie. tent and test are acceptable, but type and help should be removed). Currently, for some reason, my code seems to remove all entries from the dictionary and I have no idea why. Help would be much appreciated. I have also attached my code below for reference.

def filter(self,puzzle):

```
wordlist = dictionary.getWords()

newword = {i : wordlist[i] for i in range(len(wordlist)) if len(wordlist[i])==len(str(puzzle))}

string = puzzle.getState()

array = []
for i in range(len(newword)):
    n = newword[i]
    for j in range(len(string)):
        if string[j].isalpha() and n[j]==string[j]:
            continue
        elif not string[j].isalpha():
            continue
        else:
            array+=i
            print(i)
            break
array = list(reversed(array))
for i in array:
    del newword[i]
```

Some additional information:

puzzle.getState() is a function given to us that returns a string describing the state of the puzzle, eg. a-a--- or t---t- or elepha--

dictionary.getWords essentially creates a dictionary from the list of words

Thanks!

Comment: I've posted an answer, but wanted to ask why you are using a dictionary for `newword` when a list would do the same thing in a much simpler way? For example, `newlist = [word for word in wordlist if len(word)==len(puzzle)]` would give a list of only the words that are the same length as the puzzle.

Comment: @Craig I was taught that for such things it is good practice to use a dictionary instead of a list...although up till now it never crossed my mind why

Comment: I suspect that `len(str(puzzle))` isn't giving you the value you think it is.

Comment: @Craig yeah it isn't I just realised that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit late, but using regular expressions:

```
import re

def remove(regularexpression, somewords):
    words_to_remove=[]
    for word in somewords:
       #if not re.search(regularexpression, word):
        if re.search(regularexpression, word)==None:
            words_to_remove.append(word)
    for word in words_to_remove:
            somewords.remove(word)
```

For example you have the list `words=['hello', 'halls', 'harp', 'heroic', 'tests']`.

You can now do:
`remove('h[a-zA-Z]{4}$', words)` and `words` would become `['hello', 'halls']`, while `remove('h[a-zA-Z]{3}s$', words)` only leaves `words` as `['halls']`

Comment: Oh I see...regex seems quite powerful...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
newword = {i : wordlist[i] for i in range(len(wordlist)) if len(wordlist[i])==len(str(puzzle))}
```

creates a dictionary with non-contiguous keys. You want only the words that are the same length as `puzzle` so if your `wordlist` is `['test', 'type', 'string', 'tent']` and `puzzle` is 4 letters `newword` will be `{0:'test', 1:'type', 3:'tent'}`. You then use `for i in range(len(newword)):` to iterate over the dictionary based on the length of the dictionary. I'm a bit surprised that you aren't getting a KeyError with your code as written.

I'm not able to test this without the rest of your code, but I think changing the loop to:

```
for i in newword.keys():
```

will help.

Comment: may I know what is the meaning of "non-contiguous keys"? Thanks

Comment: I showed you. The keys in my example are [0,1,3] but you iterate over them in the for loop with range(len(newword)) which gives [0,1,2]. You should get a KeyError unless `newword` is an empty dictionary. I'd recommend you add some print statements to your code to see what is going on.